# Applescript run shellscript with login shell

Tags: macos, rake, applescript, rvm

I have a shell script that I'd like to be triggered by OS X's folder actions. To do so seems easy with applescript and the `do shell script` command, however the script isn't performed inside a **login shell**. My environment has system variables that are important to that script.

It is a rake command that I am actually running and the versions of rake and ruby, which are important, are managed by rvm.

Are there any easy ways to make applescript spawn and execute within a login shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't probably the right way to do it, but you could start bash or zsh as a login shell with `-l`.

```
do shell script "bash -lc " & quoted form of "env"
```

Comment: "This isn't probably the right way to do it" <-- Hey, It's unobtrusive, simple, and effective. I'd say this is precisely the right way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this apple script:

```
    tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell window 1
        do script "./myscript.sh; exit"
        repeat while busy
            delay 1
        end repeat
        close
    end tell
    end tell
```

It will use an already existing terminal window, if present.